# Trying to update div InnerHtml but nothing is happening

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an html table on my webpage that is displaying data that I am pulling from a MySql database.  When a user clicks on one of the table rows, depending on the data in the row, another div on the page is supposed to update displaying other information.  The problem is, when I try to update the inner html of the div from my c# code-behind page, nothing happens.  No errors in the dev console, no exceptions thrown, nothing.  Why is this happening and how can I fix it?  What am I doing wrong?

HTML table data that is being produced through c# code:

```
protected void PopulateUsers(bool active)
{
        ArrayList userList = new ArrayList();
        Query query = new Query();
        StringBuilder userListHTML2 = new StringBuilder();
        string userListHTML = "" +
            "<table runat=\"server\" id=\"userListTable\" class=\"table table-striped table-bordered table-hover\">" +
                "<thead>" +
                    "<tr>" +
                        "<th>User ID</th>" +
                        "<th>Name</th>" +
                        "<th>E-Mail</th>" +
                        "<th>Phone</th>" +
                        "<th>IsActive</th>" +
                    "</tr>" +
                "</thead>" +
                "<tbody>";
        string userListHTML3 = "" +
                "</tbody>" +
            "</table>";
        switch (active)
        {
            case true:
                userList = query.GetUserList(true);
                break;
            case false:
                userList = query.GetUserList(false);
                break;
        }
        foreach (User user in userList)
        {
            userListHTML2.Append(string.Format(@"
            <tr>
                <td>{0}</td>
                <td>{1}</td>
                <td>{2}</td>
                <td>{3}</td>
                <td>{4}</td>
            </tr>", user.userID, user.displayName, user.email, user.phone, user.isActive));
        }
        userListDiv.InnerHtml = userListHTML + userListHTML2 + userListHTML3;      
    }
```

jQuery/javascript code capturing  click:

```
function viewUserSpecifics(id) {
    var data = id;
    var xmlHttpRequest;
    xmlHttpRequest = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("testing.XMLHTTP");
    if (xmlHttpRequest == null) {
        alert("ajax not supported");
        return null;
    }
    xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "ManagerPopup.aspx?ID=" + data, true);
    xmlHttpRequest.send(null);
    //document.getElementById('userDataDiv').innerHTML.
}

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#userListTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function () {
                return $(this).text();
            }).get();

            //$("#< %= userIDHidden.ClientID %>").val($.trim(tableData[0]));
            //alert($.trim(tableData[0]));
            viewUserSpecifics($.trim(tableData[0]));
            return false;
        });
});
```

Receiving the http request:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateUsers(true);
    if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
    {
        string ID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
        SpecificUser(ID);
    }
}
```

Method that is supposed to be updating div inner html:

```
    protected void SpecificUser(string id)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(id);
        Query query = new Query();
        User specificUser = new User();
        specificUser = query.GetUserSpecifics(Convert.ToInt32(id));
        string newFormRow = "<div runat=\"server\" class=\"form-row\">";
        string newFormGroup = "<div runat=\"server\" class=\"form-group\">";
        string newFormGroupCol = "<div runat=\"server\" class=\"form-group col-md-6\">";
        string closeDiv = "</div>";
        string UserDataHTML1 = string.Format("" +
            newFormRow +
                "<label id=\"userIDLabel1\">User ID:</label>" +
                "<label id=\"userIDLabel2\">{0}</label>" +
            closeDiv +
            newFormRow +
                newFormGroupCol +
                    "<label id=\"lblFName\" for=\"txtFName\">First Name: </label>" +
                    "<input id=\"txtFName\" class=\"form-control\" runat=\"server\" type=\"text\" value={1} />" +
                closeDiv +
                newFormGroupCol +
                    "<label id=\"lblLName\" for=\"txtLName\">Last Name: </label>" +
                    "<input id=\"txtFName\" class=\"form-control\" runat=\"server\" type=\"text\" value={2} />" +
                closeDiv +
            closeDiv, id, specificUser.fName, specificUser.lName);
        userDataDiv.InnerHtml = UserDataHTML1;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You cannot add `runat=server` to a string and expect it to behave like a server control, it does not work that way. What you are doing with creating everything as a string is messy and will lead to errors. Use "real" controls like GridView, Repeater, Panel etc.

Comment: And do not use `System.Windows.Forms` in a webapplication.

Answer (score 0):

To update the html content you should send back a response from your C# route to the client, and update the html part by using jQuery with received data